# How to change the Background color of FloatingActiobButton (Fab) through Adadpter

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I'm trying to change the color of fab button through adapter but unfortunately it is giving me the default colors only

```
holder.fab.setBackgroundColor(pojo.getActivity_color());
```

inside my RecycleView adapter

and

```
pojo = new ParentDashBoard_Pojo("Home Work", R.drawable.ic_book_black_24dp,R.color.dashBoard_parent5);
    parentDashBoardPojoList.add(pojo);
```

Inside my MainActivity class

So the R.color.dashBoard_parent5 is not changing the color of fab

All suggestions are appreciated thanks.

Comment: use holder.fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(your color in int));

Comment: @VishvaDave i tried that also but it gives me a different  color

Comment: Different color means? which color are you getting? default?

Comment: @SnehalGongle make sure you are passing right color

Comment: @SnehalGongle using **`setBackgroundTintList()`** i'm getting right color in my device

Comment: @VishvaDave Hey Nilu's answer has solved my problem Thanks for help

Comment: @SnehalGongle he got answer by my comment.It's not fair. I have given idea first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [per my comment :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47843573/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-floatingactiobbutton-fab-through-adadpte/47843618#comment82651069_47843573)

Use

```
holder.fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(your color in int));
holder.fab.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
```

Comment: Vishva happy now

Comment: @SnehalGongle not just a question of happy. but its me to give idea first that's why. But anyways happy to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use [**`setBackgroundTintList()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html#setBackgroundTintList(android.view.View,%20android.content.res.ColorStateList))

> Applies a tint to the background drawable.
>
> This will always take effect when running on API v21 or newer. When running on platforms previous to API v21, it will only take effect if view implements the `TintableBackgroundView` interface.

**Sample code**

```
fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(this,pojo.getActivity_color())));
fab.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
```

Instead of this

```
holder.fab.setBackgroundColor(pojo.getActivity_color());
```

Comment: @SnehalGongle glad it help

Comment: I have given answer first

Comment: @VishvaDave dear please check time time of ans

Comment: @Nilu surely will do

Comment: @Nilu check comment timing.

Comment: @VishvaDave sorry mate you didnt give me this part of code ContextCompat.getColor()

Comment: @SnehalGongle I thought you know andorid. sry i don't know you are coding first time

Comment: @VishvaDave AnyWay Thanks for the help

Comment: @VishvaDave but doing the above doesnt show my icons inside the fab

Comment: @SnehalGongle why are you telling me!!  Nilu will help you for this,

Comment: @SnehalGongle after setting color state also set image like this **`fab.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);`** you wii get your icon